# meaning of "conscientiously honed"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was reading an article about propaganda and I met the phrase below 
"But over subsequent centuries, the use of propaganda was conscientiously honed". What does "conscientiously honed" mean?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Conscientiously honed" means "very carefully perfected".

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you about *consciously* and *hone*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means perfectly sharpened and carved with confidence and full awareness.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it cited a definition. :)